# Ajax HoverMenuExtender is not populating CSS values

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to have Menu with AJAX hovermenuextender. But Somehow the property of HoverCssClass isn't picking up the styles from the CSS file when running Because of that issue it's not showing my menu?

Following is my code

```
<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender2" runat="Server" HoverCssClass="popupHover" PopupControlID="pnlsub" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="pnlLeftNav" PopDelay="500" OffsetX="6" />
```

Output of this code is

```
<div id="ctl00_pnlBoard" class="popupMenu">
<a id="ctl00_rptBoard_ctl00_lnkCat" class="spacer" href="/pages/page_content/town_departments_planning%20and%20economic%20development_aquifer%20protection%20agency.aspx" target="_self">Aquifer Protection Agency</a>
</div>
```

Here it is missing the inline style beside with class="popMenu".

I'm new in ASP.Net and AjAx

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem a few times and here the most common resolutions I have found:

1. First make sure you are applying the style sheet with the 'popupHover' style item in it to the page that the popup is on either by a reference on the page to the style sheet, or from a reference on a master page to the style sheet.
2. Next check the style sheet you are applying to the page for syntax and make sure there is an style entry somewhere in it that starts with .popupHover  ... it should look something like this with maybe some different attributes for the popup format inside the brackets:

   .popupHover {
   Background: #FFFFFF;
   Color: #000000;
   Border: 1px solid #000000;
   }
3. Another cause is if you are applying a theme to individual pages, make sure the .popupHover style item is in the applied theme's style sheet.

Usually one of these three resolves a missing style format issue for me. Hope this helps!